# System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException: Prefix 'xmlns' is not defined

Tags: .net, xslt

We've been running .NET 2.0 and have recently decided to upgrade to .NET 4.0 which is having some undesired affects.

I have an ASPX page which is running the XslCompiledTransform.Load() function to generate HTML, however it is now throwing an exception "Prefix 'xmlns' is not defined." since upgrading to version 4.0.

My stylesheet is declared as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="#default xmlns msxsl user ms xsl">
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove "xmlns" from the list of "exclude-result-prefixes" here, as it is not actually a namespace prefix at all. It is a reserved word used to declare namespaces.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
     xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
     exclude-result-prefixes="#default msxsl user ms xsl">
```

From the looks of it, you may need to remove 'user' too.

Comment: Thanks for your response Tim. That didn't seem to stop the exception being thrown. Same error.

Comment: actually, sorry, this was also in an include file which seems to have resolved the exception. Thanks for your response.